# JavaScript don't execute in html file

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to execute a js script on my web page to verify the entry in form before putting it on data base but it don't work, the forum accept everything i put even its wrong

thats my js code i put it in head ( i tried putting it in body too but the same problem)

```
<script>
    function test() {
      name=f.name.value;
      email=f.email.value;
      phone=f.phone.value;
      for (i=0;i< length(name) ;i++){
        if(name.charAt(name[i])<'a' || nom.charAt(name[i])>'z' || name.charAt(name[i])<'A' || name.charAt(name[i])>'Z')
          {
            alert("verify your name");
            return false;
          }
        }
  
        if (isNaN(phone) || phone.length!=8  )
            {
            alert("verify your phone number");
            return false;
            }
            at=email.indexOf('@')
            point=email.indexOf('.',at)
        if(email=="" || at==-1 || point==-1)
        {
            alert("verify your email");
            return false;
        } 
  
      }
  </script>
```

and that's the form code in html

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" name='f'  onsubmit='return test()'>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="time" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="people" id="people" placeholder="# of people" data-rule="minlen:1" data-msg="Please enter at least 1 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
          </div><div class="text-center"><button onclick="test()" type="submit" name="ok">Book a table</button></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: so where is f defined in your function?, what is length(name) or where is it defined?

Comment: how could if define it in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length(name)` broke the function (use `name.length` instead). It could therefore not return `false` and prevent the form from submitting. I also cleaned up a few other bits in your markup.

It is not considered good style to use names like `f` directly in your code, although it clearly refers to the named `form` on your page. To make your code more easy to read (and more stable in maintaining it) you should declare a constant like this:

```
const f = document.querySelector("form[name=f]");
```

This makes `f` "un-assignable" in the rest of your code. Otherwise an erroneous `f=123;`, placed somewhere in your code, might have broken the functionality.

```js
f.onsubmit=function(ev){
  const name = f.name.value,
    email = f.email.value,
    phone = f.phone.value;
  for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name.charAt(name[i]) < 'a' || nom.charAt(name[i]) > 'z' || name.charAt(name[i]) < 'A' || name.charAt(name[i]) > 'Z') {
      alert("verify your name");
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (isNaN(phone) || phone.length != 8) {
    alert("verify your phone number");
    return false;
  }
  at = email.indexOf('@')
  point = email.indexOf('.', at)
  if (email == "" || at == -1 || point == -1) {
    alert("verify your email");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="add.php" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" name='f'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="people" id="people" placeholder="# of people" data-rule="minlen:1" data-msg="Please enter at least 1 chars">
        <div class="validate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <div class="validate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"><button>Book a table</button></div>
  </form>
</body>
<script>

</script>
```

Comment: i did everything as you said but its still not working
i even copied the code as yours and no change happened

Comment: Hmmm, it works in this snippet here, so there must be an error somewhere on your page that causes an error and prevents the function from working. Have you checked your console for a possible output?

Comment: A good strategy in these cases is to "start small". remove your original script and start with a minimum event-handling function like `function(ev){ev.preventDefault(); console.log("submitting has been avoided!"); return false;}`. I don't know whether returning `false` is still necessary - but better safe than sorry ;-).

Comment: I am glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

you are not declaring your variable. like `const name=f.name.value;` also f in your decleration doesn't mean anything in your javascript. first you need to select the element you need using `queryselector` for that you can check this documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
also it is not a good idea to call the function using `onclick` in the html. call the function you want on the element you selected using queryselector with `addeventlistener` for that you can check this documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
also instead of `length(name)` you should use `name.length`

Answer (score 0):

update : with Mr carsten help i fixed the problem and here is the code if anyone needed it

```
<script lang="javascript">
  const f = document.querySelector("form[name=f]");
  f.onsubmit=function(ev){

  const name = f.name.value,
    email = f.email.value,
    phone = f.phone.value;
    pp= f.people.value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z- ]+$/;

    if( ! name.match(letters)){
      alert("Verify your name");
      return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(phone) ) {
    alert("verify your phone number");
    return false;
  }

  if (phone.length != 8){
    alert("verify your phone number");
    return false;
  }
  
}
</script>
```